# EHCache multicast peer discovery: peers verification

Tags: java, security, ehcache

How can one make sure that only trusted peers are accepted through EHCache multicast peer discovery in a security-critical application?

On other words, how to make sure that an attacker with a little application knowledge (cache names, network segment, auto-discovery ports), is not able to sniff or even manipulate EHCache content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EHCache doesn't support it out of the box, therefore a custom wrapper around EHCache that will encrypt and decrypt cached content on the fly must be implemented.

Consider using symmetric encryption and hashes instead of sensitive keys if required.